# internal links in Lektor's markdown blocks

Tags: content-management-system, markdown, lektor

I want to build a website, maybe similar to a movie database, where every page has, say, actors, director, year (it seems that Lektor can deal very well with such structured metadata), and I am thinking about how to realize internal links between pages on that site.

Say I have a text such as

> `just like in [his previous movie](link), he shows again ...`

then I guess I could use the absolute path of the linked page as link target, but that makes me very inflexible with respect to changing URL structure. Can I somehow just use the ID of the target content?

Or, better yet, can I somehow automatically obtain the title of the linked page?

> `just like in his previous movie <<link:title>>, he shows again ...`

Can I use the standard Markdown blocks for that or would I have to add some handcrafted database lookup logic?

Comment: Standard Markdown certainly does not offer such a feature. I'm not familiar with Lektor which may or may not offer such a feature as an add-on. Have you checked their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

if some contents will be changed in future. I think you can use the `databag` feature to implement it. you just modify the `databg` in case changed is need.